# How to input only password to login windows 10 using guest account?

Tags: automation, windows-10, autoit

I have a script like below

```
Send("{ENTER}")
Sleep(3000)
Send("Password")

Send("{ENTER}")
```

I want login Windows 10 but typing password using `Send` command cannot be input.
I only need input password.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Do you use RDP for the machine you're trying to send input to or do you want to automate logging in for a machine that boots up? The Windows Login Screen cannot be easily automated from the same machine, but you can launch programs etc. without being logged in as a user.

Comment: I 'm not use RDP. 
I want to automate logged in that boots up.
I know i can launch program without logged in as a user.

I need that step automate log in because in the next step i need send enter. 
So enter cannot be sended when i m in login screen